# Can I use VS2010 UI Coded tests for flash applications?

Tags: flash, visual-studio-2010, automated-tests

I'm trying to use UI Coded Tests to record a test in my flash application, but the target which adds assertions does not recognize the buttons, textboxes, and nothing more.

Is possible to do these UI tests in flash using VS2010 or I should use another tool? Do you recommend any tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash is not supported

Answer (score 1):

It actually does work with Flex, but it appears only for standard controls like list boxes, tabs, drop downs and buttons.  I just tried it yesterday.  You have to do some tweaking in some cases, and isn't that useful due to it's limitations, but at least it does do some basic UI as long as you use the standard controls and not just UI like your own sprites and such, otherwise it turns into Unknown Elements.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's Coded UI doesn't support Adobe's technology.

You can find useful tools here: [Automating QA on Flex Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521729/automating-qa-on-flex-application)